# Write in the JTextArea of another class - Java

Tags: java, swing

I have two Class, class1 and class2. How can i write content in class1 's jtextarea while i am in class2?
this is my code in class2

```
NewInvoice frame=new NewInvoice(); // NewInvoice is class1
frame.CustomerField.setText(Cliente);
frame.CodFiscField.setText("P. Iva "+ogg.Piva(id));
frame.PivaField.setText("Cod. Fisc."+ogg.CodiceFiscale(id));
this.dispose();//close class2
```

with this code it open a new class1 while i want that it write in the same class1. Can someone help me?

Comment: Pass a reference of `class1` to `class2`, add a method in `class1` that allows you to pass a `String` to it and which will append the text of the `JTextArea`

Comment: Also make sure the Jtext area you are writing to in the other class is declared public, or else you wont be able to access it like you want.

Comment: ok, in class1 i added this method CustomerChoose frame=new CustomerChoose(this); and in class2 NewInvoice.CustomerField.setText(Cliente); but error is non static variable customerfield cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: ok thank everyone, fixed. i forgot to declear customers field publicstatic